# what is the keyboard shortcut to the main menu in android studio running on ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

In windows OS the 'alt' changing the focus to the main menu.

In my case the 'alt' invoked the system menu and even after that i change this shortcut & "freed" the 'alt' button the 'alt' don't change focus to the main menu.

In other words , what is the name of this operation in the android-studio KeyMap so i could assign new shortcut ?